# Where does jQuery send error messages?

Tags: jquery, debugging

I had this code:

```
var location = . . .
$body.append('<img class="bgimg" src="' + location+'>');
```

and it wasn't working.  I checked the console for output (there wasn't any) and tried multiple different things (including checking the page source and the Elements tab in Developer Tools) before noticing I had forgotten the `"` before the `>` at the end.

So, my question is:  jQuery was obviously smart enough to not add a malformed element -- but did it generate an error message about that, and if so, where did it put it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery doesn't write errors anywhere. If an error occurs and jQuery doesn't catch it, it'll end up getting reported to the console by the script engine, but jQuery itself doesn't do any error reporting of that sort.

I think this is more because it doesn't detect the error than anything else. For instance, in this case, it boils down to line 4631 in jQuery v1.12.2 (unminified):

```
tmp.innerHTML = wrap[ 1 ] + jQuery.htmlPrefilter( elem ) + wrap[ 2 ];
```

...which, with your string, is effectively:

```
tmp.innerHTML = '<img class="bgimg" src="...>';
```

The browser doesn't raise an error for that (Chrome doesn't, anyway), but it also doesn't add any elements to `tmp`. So jQuery ends up with nothing to append. It didn't *intentionally* not append anything, it just didn't see anything to append when adding that string.

Comment: So if you ask jQuery to do something, and it chooses not to, there is no notification anywhere?

Comment: Is it strange for you?

Comment: @EthanFurman: Right. Usually I suspect it's not an intentional omission so much as a by-product of something else.

Comment: @EthanFurman: I've updated the answer with a bit more information on why there was no error in this specific situation.

Comment: Thank you.  Guess I'll  double check my strings first in the future. *sigh*

Answer (score 0):

jQuery has no error reporting.

Because jQuery is written in JavaScript any invalid jQuery/JavaScript code will cause in error messages in the console of your browser (Press <kbd>F12</kbd>).

This is very tricky, because you have to be very carefull to debug your code:

```
$("mysuperclass").hide();
```

won't work, because you forgot to prepend with `.` to use a class. Although, it COULD be a valid selector, if you have custom html with a tag named `mysuperclass`.

And, thinking about it: do you think, it should shout an error message if you try to hide an element which is already hidden?

Comment: Trying to hide an already hidden element is not necessarily  an error.  Failing to append a new element because it was malformed is an error.  Guess I better start using a linter.